# Python hmac en C#

Tags: python, c#

Requiero implementar el siguiente código de python en C#, pero el resultado que se obtiene es diferente.

Código de Python:

```
import hmac 
import hashlib 
import json

from urllib.parse import unquote

API_SECRET = '12345qwer'

api_key_bytes = bytes(API_SECRET, 'utf-8')

data= {"usuario":"jalea@ejemplo.com.co","contraseña":"1245rty"}

data_str = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)

print('data_str: ',repr(data_str))

signature = hmac.new(api_key_bytes,msg=data_str.encode('utf-8'),digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

print('Data:',signature)
```

Código de C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

Login objlogin = new Login() { usuario = "jalea@ejemplo.com.co", contraseña = "1245rty" };

byte[] key= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345qwer"); HMACSHA256 hmac = new(key);

var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objlogin).ToString()));
var resultado = Convert.ToHexString(hash).ToUpper();
```

Necesito que en C# me dé igual que en Python.

En python imprime:
data_str:  '{"usuario": "jalea@ejemplo.com.co", "contraseña": "1245rty"}'
Data: 2B96764A01A1EEC3B981EDBEBDFCE8A4FF7E53F5BC57A9461524B43BC9E7C374

En C# imprime: 0FC2F1EC9CDE89A88457D1B8B3C1A221774D924596F361A6379A27182DF8D322

Comment: Mira si te puede ayudar [How to match HMACSHA256 between C# & Python](https://medium.com/@chris.mckee/how-to-match-hmacsha256-between-c-python-f7b42d01cbf5).

Comment: Imprime tanto desde python como desde C#, la cadena que obtienes al convertir los datos a json, antes de pasarlos al hmac. Sospecho que esas cadenas sean diferentes (por ejemplo que uno de los lenguajes inserte retornos de carro o espacios en lugares en que el otro no lo hace, o que codifique de diferente forma los caracteres unicode que pueda haber dentro de las cadenas del json).

Comment: Por cierto que ejecutando tu código python a mi me sale un hmac diferente. ¿Puedes imprimir el contenido de la variable `data_str` con `print(repr(data_str))` para asegurarnos de que tu versión y la mía están trabajando sobre la misma cadena?

Comment: @abulafia modifique el código para imprimir la variable data_str como me indicaste

Comment: Quería comentar que ya me funciono: el inconveniente estaba en que en Python al convertir a json agrega un espacio en blanco después de la , y de los : y en c# al convertir a json no estaban esos espacios en blanco, hice lo siguiente JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objlogin).ToString().Replace(",",", ").Replace(":", ": ")  y ya las cadenas que se imprimen son iguales tanto en pyhton como en C#. Muchas gracias @abulafia

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia se debe a que en el código de Python se está utilizando la función json.dumps() para serializar el objeto data a una cadena JSON y luego se está codificando esta cadena a bytes mediante data_str.encode('utf-8'). En cambio, en el código de C# se está utilizando la función JsonConvert.SerializeObject() de la biblioteca Newtonsoft.Json para serializar el objeto objlogin a una cadena JSON, pero luego se está convirtiendo esta cadena a una cadena de bytes mediante la función Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().

Para hacer que el código de C# produzca el mismo resultado que el de Python, debes cambiar la línea donde se convierte la cadena JSON a bytes a la siguiente:

```
var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objlogin)));
```

De esta manera, se estará utilizando el mismo método de serialización y codificación de bytes que se utiliza en el código de Python. También debes eliminar la llamada a la función ToString() que se encuentra después de JsonConvert.SerializeObject(), ya que esta función ya devuelve una cadena.